# Optimized containing of same-size squares in rectangles

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, rectangles, knapsack-problem, packing

Suppose that we have several squares of the same size. We want to draw `n` rectangles (red and yellow rectangles here) to contain these squares.

**The goal is to have the least wasted space possible.**

In the example below, `n = 2` and the solution on the right is preferred because it results in only one wasted space.

Are there any known algorithms already in place to solve these kind of problems?

**UPDATE:**
The arrangement of the squares is arbitrary and they are always above the X axis!

**UPDATE2:**
To make the question easier, let's assume that the so called container rectangles are on top of each other! (Red and yellow rectangles here)

[image]

***A little more complicated case:***
let's assume two rectangles are used for this one too. As it can be seen, the 3rd solution results in the least wasted space.

[image]

Comment: 1st: you can brute-force this problem, 2nd: use a greedy algorithm, 3rd: build a tree and cut the subtrees which have too much wasted spaces

Comment: whats up with a overlapping red/yellow box? allowed or not?

Comment: @Thomas Brute force seems to be slow. Because this is the problem in its simplest form I may have many rectangles.

Comment: does these boxes always start at the y = 0 position? or can they stand in the air?

Comment: @Thomas The red and yellow rectangles are used to contain as much rectangles as possible.

Comment: You can probably solve this with dynamic programming. However, we need to know some more specifications, like are the green boxes always in a row and in decreasing order of height? Also, how big is n for you?

Comment: @arghbleargh All of the conditions are arbitrary. They do not have a specific order. For n let's say it won't be bigger that 10-20. But since I'm going to use this in another for loop I want an optimized solution for performance reasons.

Comment: The question is updated a bit.

Comment: What is the cost of an extra rectangle relatively to a wasted square? Can you define a precise cost function based on the number of wasted squares and number of needed rectangles?

Comment: @StefanHaustein The number of rectangles are limited, `n = 2` in the above example. The goal is to achieve the minimum waste using these two rectangles.

Comment: Please give us a clue about the actual numbers of squares and rectangles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The numbers of squares can reach 20000 and the number of container rectangles may reach 10-20.

Comment: Please see the update question. Another example is provided.

Comment: I have no proof but this looks like an untractable problem. Even an approximate solution might be very costly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust From what I have learned so far, it seems a Knapsack problem but I may be wrong.

Comment: Due the geometric nature of the problem, this looks harder than the Knapstack. Maybe for some particular geometry one can show a reduction to the standard Knapstack, which would establish the untractability. Given the size of the problem, I would be pretty pessimistic. Possibly try a multiscale approach.

Comment: do you realy need the 100% correct result? or an extrem good result? because you can "solve" this with a genetic algorithm

Comment: @Thomas Thanks Thomas, An extreme good result can be acceptable as well.

Comment: Do the boxes always consist of columns on the floor? ​ (as opposed to, say, boxes floating in the air, or a plus sign formed from 5 boxes) ​ Does overlap of the rectangles count as "wasted space"? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer All the container boxes sit on top of each other. And they do not overlap each other.

Comment: Are "they" the boxes or the rectangles? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Container boxes or rectangles (Red and yellow ones) contain the green boxes/rectangles. All of the rectangles sit on top of each other. There is no overlap.

Answer (score 2):

This question is almost identical to a hiring puzzle that ITA Software posed, called ["Strawberry Fields"](https://web.archive.org/web/20130821070911/http://www.itasoftware.com/careers/puzzle_archive.html) (scroll down for Strawberry Fields; change the greenhouse cost from 10 to 0). I can confirm that integer programming, specifically [branch and price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_price) where the high-level decisions are whether to put two squares in the same rectangle, works very, very well for this problem. Here's my [custom solver](http://www.davideisenstat.com/projects/strawberry_fields-December_2012.tbz), written in C. You'll need to change the greenhouse cost in `strawberry_fields.h` from 10 to 0.

Comment: Thank you David. I will need to read your solution in depth to see how I can apply it to this.

Answer (score 1):

This type of rectangle cover is hard (NP-hard actually, you can use it to solve the Rectangle Cover Problem), but you can solve this with integer linear programming, as follows:

```
minimize sum[i] take[i] * area[i]
st
sum[i] take[i] == n
for every filled cell x,y:
    sum[rectangle i covers x,y] take[i] == 1
take[i] in { 0, 1 }
```

Where the lists of rectangles contains only "reasonable" rectangles that you might need. ie only rectangles that cannot be made smaller without uncovering some filled cell, and you can skip certain "interior rectangles" that you can tell can never be part of a solution because they would leave a shape that's harder to cover. Generating those rectangles is a fun exercise in its own right, but generating too many isn't a big problem, just slower. In the solution, any `take[i]` that is 1 corresponds to a rectangle that you take.

You can throw this into any available solver, such as GLPK (free) or Gurobi (commercial and academic licenses available).

This should generally be faster than brute force, because the linear relaxation (same model as above, but the last constraint converted to `0 <= take[i] <= 1`) can be used to guide the search, and various plane cutting tricks can be applied.

More advanced tricks can be found in [this paper](http://www.or.rwth-aachen.de/research/publications/rcover-wea.pdf), such as tricks that use the fractional solution from the linear relaxation.

Comment: Thank you harold. I was wondering what would be the number of cases assuming that there a `n` number of container rectangles, and `Nr` number of rows of squares. And also assuming that at each row only one container sits!

Comment: @Vahid what do you mean by "cases"?

Comment: For example let's say there a 7 number of rows of squares and 3 rectangles at hand to contain these. We know that only one container can be placed at each row. 1-1-5,
1-2-4,
1-3-3,
1-4-2,
1-5-1,

2-1-4,
2-2-3,
2-3-2,
2-4-1,

3-1-3,
...

Comment: by 1-1-5 I mean that if we place the first container with a height of 1 square at first row, and the second container with a height of 1 square at the second row, the 3rd container with a height of 5 square needs to be place above them to cover all the squares.

Comment: @Vahid why must there be only 1 per row?

Comment: It doesn't have to be! This is just a brute-force method! In one case we consider 1-1-5 in the next one 1-2-4 and so on we reach cases like 4-2-1 or 5-1-1 and then we calculate which one has the least waste. I was wondering how to calculate the number of these cases . I wanted to see if a brute-force method is feasible or not!